# Update a column based on another column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a column in Table A based on a value in another column of Table B.

Table A:

| Member ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 1 | 105 |
| 2 | 201 |
| 2 | 205 |
| 3 | 301 |
| 3 | 305 |

Table B:

| Member ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101: Leg |
| 1 | 105: Back |
| 2 | 201: Arm |
| 2 | 205: Hip |
| 3 | 301: Wrist |
| 3 | 305: Foot |

So what I'm trying to do is have the code in Table A update to what's in Table B. So instead of Member ID #1 having 101 and 105 as codes, it would be 101: Leg and 105: Back instead.

Below is what I've tried so far but with no success.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET code = SUBSTRING(TableB.code, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', TableB.code+'X')-1)
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB
ON TableA.Member_ID = TableB.Member_ID
```

Comment: I would not even worry about the member id. It appears you could just update the code in table a based on what is in b. That is, if the codes are all uniform.

Comment: Why not fix the design and put `105` and `Back` in separate columns? *Don't* store delimited data in your database, it breaks basic normalisation rules.

Comment: @Larnu I didn't create the database, it's just how someone else designed it. I don't have permissions to change it

Comment: @RossBush so like? UPDATE TableA
SET code = TableB.code
FROM TableB
WHERE TableA.code = TableB.code

Comment: @Brockytoosocky What version of SQL Server is it?

Comment: @Brockytoosocky - Some variation thereof, In an attempt to get around the situation with your join where Member with ID=1 could have 1 record in TableA and 100 records in TableB with different codes.

Comment: @LuisLL SQL Server 16

Comment: No that's the SSMS version try `select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')`

Comment: @LuisLL sorry, misspoke. 16. Was looking at the wrong thing on my computer

Comment: Fix the database normalization and create a view for this older "design"

Answer (score 1):

If you "must" store delimited data in your database, then you can actually achieve this with a `LIKE`:

```sql
UPDATE A
SET Code = B.Code
FROM dbo.TableA A
     JOIN dbo.TableB B ON A.MemberID = B.MemberID
                      AND B.Code LIKE A.Code + '%';
GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/obXo4DaG)

Of course, what you should really be doing is fixing your design; don't store delimited data in your database. Presumably you should have a different table for your codes and then a foreign key to the id (which I assume is the first value). Presumably, as well, that value should be an `int` not a `varchar`. This results in something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Code (CodeID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Code PRIMARY KEY,
                       CodeValue varchar(7) NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Code (CodeID, CodeValue)
SELECT DISTINCT
       LEFT(Code,CHARINDEX(':',Code) -1),
       TRIM(STUFF(Code,1,CHARINDEX(':',Code),''))
FROM dbo.TableB;
GO

UPDATE dbo.TableB
SET Code = LEFT(Code,CHARINDEX(':',Code) -1)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableB ALTER COLUMN Code int NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA ALTER COLUMN Code int NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableB ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableB_Code FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES dbo.Code (CodeID);
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableA_Code FOREIGN KEY (Code) REFERENCES dbo.Code (CodeID);
```

Then you can get the code id and value with a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT A.MemberID,
       CONCAT(C.CodeID,': ',C.CodeValue) AS Code
FROM dbo.TableA A
     JOIN dbo.Code C ON A.Code = C.CodeID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZB72enq)

Comment: Exactly: "don't store delimited data in your database" 
A database with higher normal form  does tend to be "better" IMHO  as long as you don't go overboard ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization